# Append a selected option to a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two selectors in ERB. They use the Chosen plugin:

```
<%= select_tag :provinces, 
  options_for_select(DataHelper::all_provinces_captions.zip(DataHelper::all_provinces_ids)), 
  {:multiple => true, class: 'chosen-select chzn-select', 
  :data => {:placeholder => 'Filter Provinces/States'}}
%>
  <%= f.select :province_ids,
  (DataHelper::all_provinces_captions.zip(DataHelper::all_provinces_ids)),
  { include_blank: true }, 
  {multiple: true, data: {placeholder: 'Filter Provinces/States'} }
%>
```

I am trying to copy the options from one of the selectors to the other one, while keeping the selected options still selected, however it is not working. Here is the Javascript function I have tried:

```
var selectedVals = [];

$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function() {
  $("#provinces option:selected").each(function () {
    console.log ("this value is " + ($(this).val()));
    selectedVals.push($(this).val());
  });
  $("#education_plan_province_ids").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedVals.length; i++) {
    console.log (selectedVals[i] + " selected");
    $("#education_plan_province_ids").append($("<option>" + selectedVals[i] + "</option>").attr('selected', true));
  }
  selectedVals = [];
});
```

Is there another alternative to `attr('selected', true)` ?

Comment: try this `$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function() {
         $("#education_plan_province_ids").empty();
         $("#provinces option:selected").each(function () {
            $("#education_plan_province_ids").append($("<option>" + this.value + "</option>").prop('selected', true));
      });`

Comment: I think your problem is the bracket position in '    $("#education_plan_province_ids").append($("<option>" + selectedVals[i] + "</option>")).attr('selected', true);' must be add to option element not parent one as following '    $("#education_plan_province_ids").append($("<option>" + selectedVals[i] + "</option>").attr('selected', true));'

Comment: I'll edit that, thanks! The problem still is there however @mdameer

Comment: @bipen I'll give that a try, be right with you

Comment: @bipen that is the correct answer! can you post it so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function() { 
    $("#education_plan_province_ids").empty(); 
    $("#provinces option:selected").each(function () {
         $("#education_plan_province_ids").append($("<option>" + this.value + "</option>").prop('selected', true)); 
    });
});
```

I am using `prop` here and getting rid of extra array (which I think is not needed but you can use it if you want). Also you had parenthesis in wrong place for `option`.